# How to build a typescript interface for autoNumeric.js

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a typescript file for *autoNumeric.js* in the same fashion as *accounting.d.ts*. I cannot figure out the signature of the method *autoNumeric*. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its : https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric then a quick start:

```
interface JQuery{
    autoNumeric:any;
}
```

This will let you do:

```
$('someSelector').autoNumeric('init', {options});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm talking about. This works perfectly, thank you!